# Dealing with Git fatal: Invalid revision range

Tags: git, atlassian-crucible

I am having an issue with Crucible and  Git commit. 
Crucible hangs on

```
>git whatchanged --always --reverse --date-order -m --no-abbrev --no-renames 9e00d1317c4363f73b7deb5caf5096c69e646b81..641c20936dbec78308d1bfa06d14f174f9d7df1d --pretty=format:C:%H%nP:%P%nA:%aN%nE:%aE%nR:%cN%nF:%cE%nD:%at%nS:%s%nB:%b%n@@fe_body_end@@
```

with the error:

```
fatal: Invalid revision range 9e00d1317c4363f73b7deb5caf5096c69e646b81..641c20936dbec78308d1bfa06d14f174f9d7df1d
```

Apparently there is an error in the

```
>git show 641c20936dbec78308d1bfa06d14f174f9d7df1d
fatal: bad object 641c20936dbec78308d1bfa06d14f174f9d7df1d
```

What is the best way to correct such problems? 
Git fsck leads to no errors...

> git fsck --full
>       Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
>       Checking objects: 100% (21169/21169), done.
>       dangling commit 50062154743dbc78837af62cc49388f9fabe5b58
>       dangling blob 4b82dcbd1bb49f865e5069f31d50cd9304e31c3e

Comment: I had a similar error with symfony2 and searching on google led me here, so (for the benefit of anyone with a similar issue) here is how I solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231081/git-invalid-revision-range-symfony2-composer-external-bundle/27231082#27231082

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have not locally pull the commit
"641c20936dbec78308d1bfa06d14f174f9d7df1d".

```
git checkout <branch_with_commit_641c20936dbec78308d1bfa06d14f174f9d7df1d>
git pull
git show 641c20936dbec78308d1bfa06d14f174f9d7df1d
```

Comment: This was the issue I'm having, checked out to master and did a `git pull`, diff is showing now 

Answer (score 1):

this usually happens when someone forces a push across branches, or otherwise messes with the revision history. (like modifying history commits etc)

you may need to recreate the branch.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the changelog until a successful build, turn it back on afterwords, should be resolved.