# Git Invalid revision range Symfony2 composer external bundle

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                           
  Failed to execute git log 18efcf67d236d5bbf46ac67820250dffd0474b6e..94e2146f525fa1367e15646fa273e5b34f921e68 --pretty=format:"%h - %an: %s"  
  fatal: Invalid revision range 18efcf67d236d5bbf46ac67820250dffd0474b6e..94e2146f525fa1367e15646fa273e5b34f921e68
```

I had this error when I created a custom external Symfony2 bundle and accidentally tagged it with 0.1 and then changed it to 1.0.0. (I had also changed the parent project's `composer.json` from: `"bundle/mycustombundle": "0.1."` to `"bundle/mycustombundle": "1.0."` to accommodate this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem was that it had become confused with the tags when I was trying to update to 1.0.1 (the three digit 1.0.1 doesn't follow on properly from the two digit 0.1 tag).

To solve it I:

1. Manually deleted `mycustombundle` from `myparentsymfonyproject/vendors/bundle/mycustombundle`
2. Deleted the `composer.lock` file from `myparentsymfonyproject`
3. Did a `composer update -vvv bundle/mycustombundle` (this downloaded the correctly tagged `mycustombundle` repo)
4. Did a `composer install -vvv --prefer-source` (this created a correct `composer.lock` file (`--prefer-source` will install using the folders that already exist instead of re-downloading them all)

There might be an easier way to fix it by clearing some form of composer cache, but this worked for me.